# c++ object link order visual studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, static-variables

Im having problem with visual studios 2013.  I am building a large c++ project with many classes.  The problem is several of those classes are static or have static objects of themselves with predefined values.  Now the problem is that some of these classes rely on the static versions of other objects.  Yet upon debugging I can see that one of these static objects is being initialized with a static object that has yet to be initialized.  Is there a way to define the order the objects are initialized?  From what I can see from searching I cant specify the linking order and even if I could that doesnt determine static object initialization order.

Would separating the objects out into static libraries help?  Or is there an easy way to tell it what order the static objects should be initialized?  Or do I need to find another way to initialize them in the correct order?

Comment: You might want to read about [the static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). The problem is that static initialization order between [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) have no specified order.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yeah that is exactly my problem.  The solutions offered though are to wrap the static object in a function but how can I do that with static class objects?  So now Im looking at 2 other possible solutions.  1)Is the order that static libraries linked determine their static object initalization?  So lets say my program has 2 static libraries.  Library 1 depends on library 2.  Would this mean that any static objects in library 2 get initialized first?  2)change all static objects that depend on other static to unique_ptr and have a function initialize them.